# How to use a chisel3.experimental.ChiselEnum in an I/O port?

Tags: scala, enums, chisel

Consider this code:

```scala
import chisel3.experimental.ChiselEnum

object MyEnum extends ChiselEnum {
  val A, B = Value
}

class UseEnumIO extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val out = Output(Bool())
  })

  io.out := MuxLookup(io.in, false.B, Array(
    MyEnum.A -> true.B,
    MyEnum.B -> true.B
  ))
}
```

I need to use an IO port which is supposed to be a `ChiselEnum` object in a `MuxLookup`.

This is the error message I got from SBT:

```
[error]  found   : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[(MyEnum.Type, chisel3.core.Bool)]
```

while Scala inferred that `[S <: chisel3.UInt,T <: chisel3.Data]`

I also tried `val in = Input(MyEnum.Type)` which gave me a more serious error.

```scala
val defaultVersions = Map(
  "chisel3" -> "3.2-SNAPSHOT
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why this doesn't work, but the following work-around might help.
Try

```
  io.out := MuxLookup(io.in, false.B, Seq(
    MyEnum.A.asUInt -> true.B,
    MyEnum.B.asUInt -> true.B
  ))
```

it seems to work to me. 
I'll keep looking for a reason that the more obvious simple syntax does not work.

Answer (score 2):

`MuxLookup` requires UInts (or Bools) for the selector. From the [API docs](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/util/MuxLookup$.html):

```
def apply[S <: UInt, T <: Data](key: S, default: T, mapping: Seq[(S, T)]): T
```

This is probably an oversight, `MuxLookup` predates `ChiselEnum` by a lot of time so it wasn't made with it in mind, I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/1058) to support this use case. You can use Chick's workaround in the meantime.